# How to insert a new row between another rows in gridview boundfield?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, gridview

I have a `gridview` like below picture:

[image]

In this `gridview` I want to introduce a new row that does not have any completely out of the cell where the last "Grand Total" there to put a variable mine.

But the question is, how introduce a new row among others?

My code is:

```
        Dim Qty As Double = 0
        Dim CostCategory As Double = 0
        Dim AssemblyDate As String = Nothing

        If GridView1.Rows.Count <> 0 Then
            For x As Integer = 0 To GridView1.Rows.Count - 1
                For y As Integer = 0 To GridView1.Columns.Count - 1

                    If y = 0 And GridView1.Rows(x).Cells(1).Text = AssemblyDate Then
                        GridView1.Rows(x).Cells(1).Text = ""
                    End If

                    If GridView1.Rows(x).Cells(1).Text <> Nothing Then
                        AssemblyDate = GridView1.Rows(x).Cells(1).Text
                    End If


                    If y = "9" Then
                        Qty = Convert.ToDouble(GridView1.Rows(x).Cells(9).Text)
                    End If

                    If y = "13" Then
                        CostCategory = Convert.ToDouble(GridView1.Rows(x).Cells(13).Text)
                    End If

                    If y = "14" Then
                        GridView1.Rows(x).Cells(14).Text = Qty * CostCategory
                        GridView1.Rows(x).Cells(14).HorizontalAlign = HorizontalAlign.Center
                    End If

                    If GridView1.Rows(x).Cells(y).Text = "Yes" Then
                        GridView1.Rows(x).Cells(y).BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.LawnGreen

                    ElseIf GridView1.Rows(x).Cells(y).Text = "No" Then
                        GridView1.Rows(x).Cells(y).BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red
                    End If
                Next
            Next
End if
```

before that code i have a query where i fill my gridview:

```
Dim myQuery As String = SelectQuery & WhereQuery
SqlDataSource1.SelectCommand = myQuery
SqlDataSource1.DataBind()
GridView1.DataSourceID = "SqlDataSource1"
GridView1.DataBind()
```

Thanks a lot!

Comment: You can add new row in datasource and reassign that datasource to gridview.

Comment: In footer yes, but not between two rows.

Answer (score 0):

Try using this

```
DataRow dr = tblTable.NewRow(); //Create New Row
dr["ColumnName"] = "Legs";              // Set Column Value
tblTable.Rows.InsertAt(dr, 11); // InsertAt specified position
```

For VB.Net Grid View

```
Dim rowNumber As Integer = dGrid.CurrentCell.RowNumber() + 1 
Dim myNewRow As DataRow = myDataTable.NewRow() 
myDataTable.Rows.InsertAt(myNewRow, rowNumber) 
myDataTable.AcceptChanges()
```

Comment: For vb.net, you know?

Comment: new rows is not a member of 'system.web.ui.webcontrols.Gridview'